# sql query only putting in one record not multiple?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hi I'm just trying to do this php/sql query, I'm attempting to enter more than one record at a time using this code but it's only entering one, not the others...

CODE:

```
    <?php
        $results=$_POST['results'];
        $day=$_POST['day'];
        $lmID=$_POST['lmID'];
        $cID=$_POST['cID'];
        $count_cID = count($_POST['cID']);

        for($i=0;$i<$count_cID ;$i++){
        $_results = mysql_escape_string($results[$i]);
        $_day = mysql_escape_string($day[$i]);
        $_lmID = mysql_escape_string($lmID[$i]);
        $_cID = mysql_escape_string($cID[$i]);

        $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO Club (results, day, lmID, cID) VALUES ('$_results', '$_day', '$_lmID', '$_cID')");
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
    }

    ?>
```

HTML FORM:

```
            League Match ID:
            <?php echo $lmID;?> <input type="hidden" name="lmID[]" value="<?php echo $lmID; ?>" >
            Competitor ID:
            <?php echo $cID;?> <input type="hidden" name="cID[]" value="<?php echo $cID; ?>" >
            Result:
            <input type="text" name="results[]">
            Day:
            <input type="text" name="day[]">

            <input type="submit" name="submit">
        </form>
```

Comment: 1. You need to use `mysql_error()` to see why your qwuery fails. 2. mysql_* functions are deprecated. You shouldn't be using them. 3. `mysql_escape_string()` is *extra* deprecated. It has been obsolete for a ling time. Use `mysql_real_escape_string()` instead.

Comment: show the html form as well

Comment: and check ur tables  and fields name too :)

Comment: 4. You are calling mysql_query twice!

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO Club (results, day, lmID, cID) VALUES ('$_results', '$_day', '$_lmID', '$_cID')");
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Should be:

```
$sql = <<<EOF
INSERT INTO Club (results, day, lmID, cID) 
VALUES ('{$_results}', '{$_day}', '{$_lmID}', '{$_cID}')
EOF;
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

As mentioned in other comments, please do not use mysql_ database functions - use PDO or mysqli_  functions. [mysql_query](https://www.php.net/mysql_query) is deprecated (for good reason). With the other libraries, it seems your statement would also be a candidate for PREPARE followed by EXECUTE. e.g. using PDO....

```
$sql = <<<EOF
INSERT INTO Club (results, day, lmID, cID) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
EOF;
$stmt = $db->prepare( $sql);

for($i=0;$i<$count_cID ;$i++){
    // escape your data here - you might not need to with PDO
    $result = $stmt->execute( array( $_results, $day, $_lmID, $_cID));
}
```

Comment: I would better do something like this: `$sql = "INSERT INTO Club (results, day, lmID, cID) VALUES ('$_results', '$_day', '$_lmID', '$_cID')"; $result = mysql_query($sql);`

Comment: You can use any tag to end a HEREDOC - I just use EOF

Comment: Hi i pretty much used the code you put above but the whole thing just goes grey when I do $sql = <<<EOF and even upon closing it, it's still grey..

Comment: Works for me - only going by PhpStorm syntax check as don't have a DB to hook it up to... see [heredoc syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) and make sure you haven't put any stray spaces in

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `$count_cID` is more than 1 (one). Which it is not, looks like. The reason I'm referring to this variable is you are comparing `$i` to it, and in your `for` loop, if it's not greater than 1, then the loop contents will be executed once only, as on the second try the condition will not validate anymore.

Comment: As expected. I guess this should fix your problem: Replace `$count_cID = count($_POST['cID']);` with `$count_cID = $_POST['cID'];` and `$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO Club (results, day, lmID, cID) VALUES ('$_results', '$_day', '$_lmID', '$_cID')");` with `$sql = "INSERT INTO Club (results, day, lmID, cID) VALUES ('$_results', '$_day', '$_lmID', '$_cID')";`. Let me know.

Comment: I get the error "Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 1" and it is still only inserting one

Comment: and that error repeats a few times with sometimes the number changing to 2

Comment: Try `echo $count_cID;` right before `for($i=0;...` one more time and post back the results.

Comment: Number is more than 1, I entered 4 things in and it counted 4

Comment: See above comment, I need to see the value to help you further. If you have one input box, you would have one value only, you can't post a php array with one input field. You would probably need to adjust html or php for this to work. Let me know the value of `$count_cID`.

Comment: I am testing with two records. In each record there is a total of four inputs that go into the database however TWO of them are hidden inputs and two are values I have to enter.

Comment: So for example:

Record #1. ValueA 10. ValueB 15. InputC. ? Input D. ?
Record #2. ValueA 10. ValueB 15. InputC. ? Input D. ?

Comment: So my guess is, it's showing four because I entered four

Comment: So you would need to submit the form twice to get two entries saved to database. As the values you provide in the form input fields might be different for each submission. If that's the case, I can help you with converting the code so it runs once per each submission, otherwise something's wrong here.